# programatically getting stack trace when a System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out occurs

Tags: asp.net, timeout, httprequest, stack-trace

In Asp.Net we are using the global Application error handler to log all exception that occur. The logs are extremely helpful of course. However, when a request time out occurs, the exception does not include the trace of the code that was being executed when the timeout occurred because the exception is not thrown by the code itself.
Is there anyway get that data programatically ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find that through the event viewer in the application logs.  You can also run something like elmah or glimpse to log and track exceptions on your web application.  They will give you some additional info as well as give you a better view of what's going on in your web application

Comment: we already have error logging, I'm asking about this specific problematic exception. I updated the question, I hope it's clearer now.